# How to create THREE.PerspectiveCamera object inside setState in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, three.js, setstate

I am using three.js and react.js. Right now i am creating **THREE.PerspectiveCamera** object like this way.

```
init = () => {
    this.state.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(25, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
// others code
}
```

It is working fine but it's giving me a warning about this

```
Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()
```

now if i tried to do this

```
this.setState({camera: new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(25, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000)})
```

it is giving me an error and its unable to create **THREE.PerspectiveCamera** object. This is the error below

error

```
Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
```

error line

```
this.state.camera.position.set(100, 0, 1000)
```

this is my state

```
this.state = {
    a: '',
    b: false,
    camera: {},
}
```

So Can anyone help me how to crate a **THREE.PerspectiveCamera** object inside **setState**?

Comment: What is the error that you get when creating a new object inside setState?

Comment: @maechler
error - Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
error line - this.state.camera.position.set(100, 0, 1000)

means its can not create the camera

Comment: Have you destructed the camera object from state and tried set the value? `const { camera } = this.state; camera.position.set(100, 0, 1000)`

Comment: @SelvaTS
something like this

 const { camera } = this.state;
 camera.setState({camera: new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(25, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000)})

Comment: @sayalok No, its wrong. Try something like `const { camera } = this.state; camera.position.set(100, 0, 1000); this.setState({ camera });`

Comment: @SelvaTS sorry dear not working 
its giving me this Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

Comment: @sayalok it seems your camera/position object is not available. Try to log the output after getting it from state. `const { camera } = this.state; console.log(camera);`

Comment: @SelvaTS yeah its can not create camera object inside setState

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187252/discussion-between-selva-ts-and-sayalok).

Comment: Where are you doing this from? Can you provide more of the code to show us the context of where you are calling setState()?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you keep the camera out of `this.state` because when you're animating it at 60 frames-per-second, React is going to try to keep track of all those state changes and cause too much overhead.

To simplify things, you should do `this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera()` then you can modify it at will with `this.camera.position.set(x, y, z)` and keep React's state tracking out of the equation.

Comment: i use this in different function how can i make it global
i tried this before
        this.context.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(25, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000); // change the degree here

but its giving me below error

TypeError: Cannot add property camera, object is not extensible